# help on typedefs - basic c/c++

Tags: c++, c

i have been going through some code and came across a statement that somehow disturbed me.

```
typedef GLfloat vec2_t[2];   

typedef GLfloat vec3_t[3];
```

From my perspective, a statement such as

```
typedef unsigned long ulong;
```

Means that **ulong** is taken to mean **unsigned long**
Now, can the statement below mean that **vec2_t[2]** is equivalent to **GLfloat**??

```
typedef GLfloat vec2_t[2];
```

Most likely, Probably its not the intended meaning. I would appreciate it if someone clears this up for me.  Thanks

Comment: This is not only true for arrays. It's also true for functions: `typedef void ft(); /* equivalent: */ ft *f; void (*f)();`

Comment: Do notice that vec2[n] (for valid index n) where vec2 has type vec2_t does have type GLfloat.  This is a symmetry from the C declaration style that many people like.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically a `typedef` has exactly the same format as a normal C declaration, but it introduces another name for the type instead of a variable of that type.

In your example, without the typedef, `vec2_t` would be an array of two `GLfloat`s. With the typedef it means the `vec2_t` is a new name for the type "array of two `GLfloat`s".

```
typedef GLfloat vec2_t[2];
```

This means that these two declarations are equivalent:

```
vec2_t x;

GLfloat x[2];
```

Answer (score 3):

C declaration syntax can be confusing, but you only need one simple rule: **read from the inside-out**.  Once you do that, just understand typedef creates another name (an alias) for a type.

The inside is the declared-identifier (or where it would go if missing).  Examples:

```
T a[2]; // array (length 2) of T
T* a[2]; // array (length 2) of pointer to T ([] before *)
T (*p)[2]; // pointer to array (length 2) of T (parens group)
T f(); // function returning T
T f(int, char*); // function of (int, pointer to char) returning T
T (*p)(int); // pointer to function of (int) returning T

T (*f(char, T(*)[2]))(int);
// f is a function of (char,
//                     pointer to array (length 2) of T)
//                 returning a pointer to a function of (int)
//                                                   returning T

typedef T (*F(char, T(*)[2]))(int);
// F is the type:
//        function of (char,
//                     pointer to array (length 2) of T)
//                 returning a pointer to a function of (int)
//                                                   returning T
// (yes, F is a function type, not a pointer-to-function)
F* p1 = 0; // pointer to F
T (*(*p2)(char, T(*)[2]))(int) = 0; // identical to p1 from the previous line
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `vec2_t` is an array of 2 GLfloats and `vec3_t` is an array of 3 GLfloats. You can then do stuff like:

```
vec2_t x;
// do stuff with x[0] and x[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create a typedef-name `vec2_t` for an array type `GLfloat[2]`, the proper syntax would be not

```
typedef GLfloat[2] vec2_t;
```

(as a beginner might expect), but rather

```
typedef GLfloat vec2_t[2];
```

I.e. the general structure of the syntax here, as it has already been said, is the same an in a variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `vec2_t` is an array of 2 `GLfloat` and that `vec3_t` is an array of 3.

[More info](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/typedef.html)

Answer (score 0):

The intent would be clearer if C syntax allowed it to be written as

```
typedef GLfloat[2] vec2_t;   

typedef GLfloat[3] vec3_t;
```

But that's not valid syntax.

Comment: Of course it's not and he's saying that.  He was just trying to show what the definition does.  +1

Comment: @Nicholaz, well to be fair, he said that after they commented. Before, he asked about its validness in the question. Not sure why and who downvoted though.